# How do you work around the need for apostrophes in certain function names?

Tags: function, naming-conventions, special-characters

When I'm programming, I often find myself writing functions that -should- (to be proper english) contain apostrophes (too bad C started everyone thinking that an apostrophe was an appropriate delimiter).  For example: `get_user's_group() -> get_users_group()` .  What do you guys do with that <strike>forced-bad-english</strike> ambiguous english?  Just ignore the apostrophe?  Create a different phrasing?

Comment: Surely its not about bad english especially concern over grammar but programming! I agree that any naming should help describe what that particular class/property/method provides and thats it.

Comment: Look on the bright side: at least you won't get any greengrocer's apostrophes.

Comment: I guess, as I mention below, it's more the ambiguity of the resulting phrases (get_users_group is my example) that bother me, more than the "it's not proper english" thing.

Comment: Easy -- use Haskell, which allows apostrophes in names!  (This is true but I mean it in jest. I've never seen apostrophes actually used this way in Haskell--only as a stand-in for the mathematical "prime" mark.)

Comment: I'd just use the apostrophe (because you can do that in tcl) :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In that case, I would do `get_group_for_user()`.

So, yes, I would "create a different phrasing" :)

Either that, or `user.get_group()`.

Answer (score 7):

```
getGroupForUser()
```

or

```
getGroupByUser()
```

Answer (score 5):

My original answer of `Ignore it, move on!` is incomplete. You should ignore the fact you can't use `'` in your method/function names. But you should continue to look at the naming of them to better explain what they do. I think this is a worthwhile pursuit in programming.

Picking on JavaScript, you *could* if you wanted to use apostrophes:

```
const user = {
    "get_user's_group": () => console.log("Naming things! Am I right?!")
}

user["get_user's_group"]()
```

But don't do that

Taking it further, you *could* if you wanted to, use a transpiler to take your grammatically correct name and transform it into something you never see.

Again with JavaScript as an example, maybe you could write a babel transform.

But don't do that

As others have said, if there is context available from an object, that's a nice option:

```
user.get_group()
```

Failing that, the context of the surrounding code should be enough to make this your choice:

```
get_users_group()
```

Answer (score 3):

How about `getGroupByUser`?

Answer (score 3):

Either `get_user_ApostropheShouldBeHereButLanguageWillNotLetMe_s_group` or just ignore it because it really doesn't matter.

Comment: It does matter for someone else reading the code as get_users_group can mean (at least) two different things.

Comment: If you have proper documentation, I don't think it would be a big deal.

Comment: It matters, but not enough to dwell on. A simple rephrasing is all that's required.

Comment: Right, that's also a big part of the problem, is that, trying for an example, get_dogs_group (a group for dogs, perhaps?) is very different from get_dog's_group -> get_dogs_group (the group that a single dog is in).  So the wording often becomes somewhat imprecise in the absence of apostrophes, unfortunately.

Comment: @Tatu Ulmanen: Ugh, no. There are many words that have multiple meanings even in a programming context (think, for example, of `static` in C++ which I think has four different meanings). But this rarely matters because of context. If there are multiple possible meanings of `get_users_group` in the same context then yes, rename. Otherwise, don't worry about it and just move on.

Comment: Well, hard to be self-documenting when the function names get ambiguous.  I'm not sure that context applies to functions very well?  If you have a completely unattached lib file with a single function in it, there's little context until you get specific and comment/make the context.  *shrugs*

Answer (score 1):

I ignore the apostraphe `getGroupyUser` and `group_from_user` are both perfectly understandable. Worrying about having correct grammer in your function names is a waste of time and distracts from the correct goal of having clear and understandable user names.

Answer (score 1):

the point of proper english in function  naming is a bit extreme ...

i mean why is the apostrophe bothering you but the _ instead of a space is not ?

Comment: Because no-one ever uses _ in normal writing/speech.  Apostrophes, on the other hand, are                                                                                pretty basic.

Comment: that was not my point ... i meant why is it ok to replace spaces and not apostrophes.. if the issues is what char to use you could replace apostropes as well with _

Comment: Fair enough.  I guess it's that _ is a efficient replacement for space, whereas apostrophe has no useful replacement that I could think of.  *shrugs*

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the programming language you may be able to use Unicode variable names, [this SO thread lists a few.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786231/programming-languages-that-allow-unicode-in-the-names-of-functions-variables-clas)

With Unicode identifiers you could use one of the [unicode apostrophes](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02bc/index.htm) to give the proper english language formatting to your variable name. Though this only speculative. And it would be hard to maintain. Actually, now that I think about it, it sounds downright evil.

Comment: i would like to see someone trying to invoke those functions .. lol

Answer (score 1):

Two points: First, don't use a name that would otherwise require an apostrophe if you can avoid it.  Second, you are right in being concerned about ambiguity.  For example, you could have:

- `getUsersGroup`: gets the group of a list of users.  If you are using an object-oriented language, this could have more information than just a group ID string.  You could also have something like `createUsersGroup`, which would create a group object from a list of users passed in.
- `getGroupOfUser`: takes in some sort of user object; returns the name of the group of the user
- `getGroupByUserId`: takes in the user's name or a unique ID associated with that user; returns the name of the group of the user

The best way to delineate the difference between all of these is to just use standard method comments that explain the method names.  This would depend on what language you are working with and what style of method comments your organization conventionally uses.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I just drop the apostrophe, but do back-ticks work? (get_user`s_group)

Answer (score 0):

`getGroupOfUser`? `getUserGroup`?

It's a programming language, not literature...

It would be `getBackgroundColour` in proper English (rather than `getBackgroundColor`)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd write `get_user_group()` rather than `get_group_for_user()` since it feels like it reads better to me. Of course, I use a programming language where apostrophes are allowed in names:

```
proc get_user's_group {id} {#...}
```

Although, some of the more prolific non-English-native European users use it as a word separator:

```
proc user'group {id} {#...}
```

to each his own I guess..